# Can't set SMTP Port in SQLCLR stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, email, permissions, smtp, sqlclr

I have a SQLCLR stored procedure that sends mail using `System.Net` (not looking for a debate of the various SQL Server Mail methods).

It allows for optionally overriding the port to use. We have this code on our servers, and it works fine, even when overriding the port.

We have a client who self-hosts this system, and it worked fine there too, UNTIL they needed to send via a different port. When I try to pass in a port on their server, I get the following error (note the error stack is coming through the call to `set_Port`):

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "SendMail":
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
>   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.set_Port(Int32 value)
>   at SqlMail.StoredProcedures.SendMail(SqlString smtpserver, SqlString smtpusr, SqlString smtppwd, SqlString MailFrom, SqlString MailToCsv, SqlString MailCcCsv, SqlString MailBccCsv, SqlString Subject, SqlString Body, SqlBoolean IsBodyHtml, SqlBoolean UseSsl, SqlInt16 Port, SqlString TargetName).

The database already has `TRUSTWORTHY` set on, and the assembly has `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` set.

I've seen people say about needing to change the trust level in .NET config files. I did a grep of all the config files, and the only ones which have trust level in them are `web.config`, which I don't **think** would apply to SQL Server, would they? But even if they do, they are all already set to `Full`.

Comment: I don't have time to test now, but if `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` doesn't work, it might need `UNSAFE`. It's worth trying.

Comment: @srutzky - huh. Odd... that seems to fix it. The port gets set fine now. (Though the Smtp Send operation is timing out, but that's a different issue.) Seems weird that `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` works on our servers, but not theirs. Interesting. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad that worked! Yes, I can post an answer. But first, is it ok if we try to figure out why there is that difference? Maybe a config difference in the Logon As account used for the NT Service for MSSQLSERVER (or Instance name)? It could be that they are using Local System and your server is using a Local or Domain account. Something like that. Also, I would highly, _highly_ recommend _not_ setting `TRUSTWORTHY` to `ON` and instead sign the Assembly, create an Asymmetric Key in `master`, create a Login from the Key, and grant the permission to that Login. I can point you to instructions.